# ChangeMenu and Timer in User Control in PB

Tags: powerbuilder

Have any have idea on how to create/use ChangeMenu and Timer method in Visual User Object (Custom). 
I'm using PB.NET 12.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Timer**

This can be replaced by embedding a Timing object (Insert / Object / Timing or a Standard Class User Object of type Timing) and code the Timing object's events.

**ChangeMenu**

It's not clear what you want to happen with ChangeMenu(), but I'll take a guess and say you call GetParent(), looping on the result until the result is a window (PFC's of_GetParentWindow() is a good example of code like this), and call ChangeMenu() on that.

Good luck,

Terry.

Comment: currently i try to move all syntax and design from window to visual user object.This syntax get an error--->   im_insp = Create m_insp
This.ChangeMenu(im_insp)---->No overload for method 'changemenu' taken '1' argument'  in user object but it was ok in window before.do you have an idea what should i do on it?

Comment: You need to parse through what needs to get moved and what doesn't, and what needs to be converted because of the change in paradigm. My suggestion above for ChangeMenu() stands, although I'd suggest you need some more in depth evaluation of whether it *should* be converted.